# Power BI Calculate variance between to rows in the same column dynamically

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, difference

I am trying to calculate the variance of projects, over different periods.
Periods are referenced as P1, P2,...

The user should be able to pick the periods that they want to compare and see the projects listed

[new table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g50ds.png)

I have tried a dax formula, but I can't find one that has more than one filter.

My DAX:

```
Variance =
VAR DIFF =
    WIP[WIP]
        - CALCULATE (
            SUM ( WIP[WIP] ),
            FILTER ( 'WIP', WIP[Index1] = EARLIER ( WIP[Index] ) )
        )
RETURN
    IF ( DIFF = VALUE ( WIP[WIP] ), 0, DIFF )
```

Can you help?

[2nd table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1SXF.png)

Comment: It's hard to understand your case. Can you add a sample data table and result sample?

Comment: You can add multiple filters to CALCULATE()

Comment: @Mik, Thank you for checking. I have added a column for the result in the table above. I think you need to click on the link. It doesn't let me post a picture.

Comment: And if it will be 3 periods? How should theresult looks like?

Comment: @Mik Hi, Thank you. I have update the table to show 3 periods.

Comment: @YolandaCB, please check

Comment: Are you working with power pivot or PBI?

Answer (score 0):

```
Variance = 
VAR currentPeriod = SELECTEDVALUE('tbl'[Period])
VAR currentObj = SELECTEDVALUE(tbl[Object])
VAR firstPeriodInSelection=
        CALCULATE(
            MIN('tbl'[Period])
            ,'tbl'[Object]=currentObj
            ,ALLSELECTED('tbl'[Period])
            ,ALLEXCEPT(tbl,tbl[Period],tbl[Object])
        )
VAR prevPeriod = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('tbl'[Period])
        ,'tbl'[Period]<currentPeriod
        ,'tbl'[Object]=currentObj
        ,ALL()
    )
VAR currentWIP = 
        CALCULATE(
            AVERAGE(tbl[WIP])
            ,ALLEXCEPT(tbl,tbl[Object],tbl[Period])
        )
VAR prevWIP =  
    CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE(tbl[WIP])
        ,ALLEXCEPT(tbl,tbl[Object])
        ,'tbl'[Period]=IF(
                          prevPeriod < firstPeriodInSelection
                         ,firstPeriodInSelection
                         ,prevPeriod
                       )
    )
RETURN
    currentWIP-prevWIP
```

Please, pay attention that on my picture you can see 2 values for one period-object. For this case I used average. So, if it will be one value for period-object then you see the value, if it will be several then you will see calculated Variance for average.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. @Mik. Unfortunately this is not show the variance. It's copying the values again?

Comment: I tested it with a table visual, and it was correct. How do you want to show the result? Can you add a screenshot of the report so, I'll understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you @Mik. I have added a second table link on the main question

Comment: PBI. The columns are not together on the table. That's I have showed a summary

Comment: what visual you are going to use? if it is a table or matrix then I need to know columns than you gonna use as rows

Comment: I cant get a clear picture about the context for the measure. So, I know only that you have a slicer for period, But then you need to put values for rows in a visual. What are this values, so could you, please, clarify how you want to show the result.

Comment: The problem is in my measure. It counts through all periods. I'll alter it today later.

Comment: Hi, please look at altered measure

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it looks like it's carrying the amount in the first month and then adding it to any variance that occurs :(

Comment: may be you can add  your pbix, or pbix with dummy data

Comment: or you correct your data table (your first screenshot, it seems has wrong figures of variance)

Comment: On your last screenshot you show variance in both directions but its not possible to show if you have 3 row for 1 object with 3 different WIP. It's only possible to compare difference with previous data in one direction. And the measure does it.

Comment: Can you show what is a result of the measure and what should be?